# Jquery Datatables Сортировка двух колонок с разными типами данных

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Есть таблица со статистикой, содержащая два столбца. Первый столбец - это случайное имя (строка), а второй - количество действий (целое число). Как мне сделать, чтобы при сортировки второго столбца, если значения одинаковые - то в первом столбце происходила сортировка по алфавиту. Более наглядно это видно на [этом скриншоте](https://yadi.sk/i/uPQfNolFD5GSmg)
Я не смог найти ничего в документации по поводу этого.
Вот мой код:

```
$('#table').DataTable({
  processing: false,
  stateSave: true,
  responsive: true,
  iDisplayLength: 25,
  order: [[1, 'desc']],
  columnDefs: [{
    targets: [0],
    orderData: [1, 1]
  }, {
    targets: [1],
    orderData: [1, 1]
  }],
  sDom: `<'row top-row'<'col-sm-2 col-xs-2 col-xxs-12'f><'col-sm-2 col-xs-2 col-xxs-12'l>
        <'col-sm-8 col-xs-8 col-xxs-12 custom-button'>>
        <'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>
        <'row'<'col-sm-12'<'table-bottom-toolbar clearfix'ip>>>`,
  columns: [
    { data: 'userName', name: 'userName' },
    { data: 'count', name: 'count' }
  ],
  data: data
});
```

Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/api/order(), примеры 3 и 4.

Comment: Пробовал, это почему-то не работает или я делаю что-то не то

Comment: Боюсь, что Вы таблицу, получение из неё данных, и отображение этих данных на экране - замешиваете в одну кучу. А это три разных хреновины, и как минимум у последних двух, а то и у всех трёх - свои сортировки. Обратите внимание на метод Draw() - он там вовсе даже не для мебели...